# Tensorflow translate training - when will it stop?

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am using example from Google's Tensorflow. I am able to run it well, but the training doesn't seem to stop as it has a `while True:` loop.
reference:
[translate.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/rnn/translate/translate.py)

Coe in `train()`:

```
while True:
  # Choose a bucket according to data distribution. We pick a random number
  # in [0, 1] and use the corresponding interval in train_buckets_scale.
  random_number_01 = np.random.random_sample()
  bucket_id = min([i for i in xrange(len(train_buckets_scale))
                   if train_buckets_scale[i] > random_number_01])
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true, at one point you can abort the training process. The moment of it depends on the model parameters you have choosen. According to the tensorflow [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/tutorials/seq2seq/index.html#sequence-to-sequence-models) it takes about 340K steps with choosen batch-size of 64.
If have selected the option to create checkpoints, you can use any of the checkpoints to check your models performance with the decoder.